# Match everything except a pattern and replace matched with string

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to use python in order to manipulate a string I have.
Basically, I want to prepend"\x" before every hex byte except the bytes that already have "\x" prepended to them.

My original string looks like this:

```
mystr = r"30336237613131\x90\x01\x0A\x90\x02\x146F6D6D616E64\x90\x01\x06\x90\x02\x0F52656C6174\x90\x01\x02\x90\x02\x50656D31\x90\x00"
```

And I want to create the following string from it:

```
mystr = r"\x30\x33\x62\x37\x61\x31\x31\x90\x01\x0A\x90\x02\x14\x6F\x6D\x6D\x61\x6E\x64\x90\x01\x06\x90\x02\x0F\x52\x65\x6C\x61\x74\x90\x01\x02\x90\x02\x50\x65\x6D\x31\x90\x00"
```

I thought of using regular expressions to match everything except /\x../g and replace every match with "\x". Sadly, I struggled with it a lot without any success. Moreover, I'm not sure that using regex is the best approach to solve such case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Regex**: [`(?:\\x)?([0-9A-Z]{2})`](https://regex101.com/r/reg9b2/2) **Substitution**: `\\x$1`

**Details**:

- `(?:)` Non-capturing group
- `?` Matches between zero and one time, match string `\x` if it exists.
- `()` Capturing group
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list `0-9` and `A-Z`
- `{n}` Matches exactly `n` times
- `\\x` String \x
- `$1` Group 1.

**Python code**:

```
import re

text = R'30336237613131\x90\x01\x0A\x90\x02\x146F6D6D616E64\x90\x01\x06\x90\x02\x0F52656C6174\x90\x01\x02\x90\x02\x50656D31\x90\x00'
text = re.sub(R'(?:\\x)?([0-9A-Z]{2})', R'\\x\1', text)
print(text)
```

**Output**:

```
\x30\x33\x62\x37\x61\x31\x31\x90\x01\x0A\x90\x02\x14\x6F\x6D\x6D\x61\x6E\x64\x90\x01\x06\x90\x02\x0F\x52\x65\x6C\x61\x74\x90\x01\x02\x90\x02\x50\x65\x6D\x31\x90\x00
```

[Code demo](http://rextester.com/KAHZKS70051)

Comment: Thanks! Mind to explain the first part, until the second '?'?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regex for this. You can use simple string manipulation. First remove all of the `"\x"` from your string. Then add add it back at every 2 characters.

```
replaced = mystr.replace(r"\x", "")
newstr = "".join([r"\x" + replaced[i*2:(i+1)*2] for i in range(len(replaced)/2)])
```

Output:

```
>>> print(newstr)
\x30\x33\x62\x37\x61\x31\x31\x90\x01\x0A\x90\x02\x14\x6F\x6D\x6D\x61\x6E\x64\x90\x01\x06\x90\x02\x0F\x52\x65\x6C\x61\x74\x90\x01\x02\x90\x02\x50\x65\x6D\x31\x90\x00
```

Comment: Elegant answer, I liked it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list with your values to manipulate as you wish, with an even simpler re pattern

```
mystr = r"30336237613131\x90\x01\x0A\x90\x02\x146F6D6D616E64\x90\x01\x06\x90\x02\x0F52656C6174\x90\x01\x02\x90\x02\x50656D31\x90\x00"

import re

pat = r'([a-fA-F0-9]{2})'
match = re.findall(pat, mystr)

if match:
    print('\n\nNew string:')
    print('\\x' + '\\x'.join(match))
    #for elem in match: # match gives you a list of strings with the hex values
    #    print('\\x{}'.format(elem), end='')

print('\n\nOriginal string:')
print(mystr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without replacing existing `\x` by using a combination of positive lookbehinds and negative lookaheads.

```
(?!(?<=\\x)|(?<=\\x[a-f\d]))([a-f\d]{2})
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##TY9NawIxEIbv@RXTpYcEtiUf7khLRURX8VLBHo2IpbFdaHVJIqS0/vY1xm115jAvM88w79Tf/mO3VU1TfdU768EaQqx5NwF6YDPav6H9p57Wgf22YrG@2@i3JWO0VT/ywDLijfMr521aU1wplKqLQsXU4YHrwGPlg1ZLHUQHxziKKbDEzhWDF4aPC4kFDlF0rwl5IQoe56P/Gzwjbv/qfHIRzd6K7PSO23@mlrmPU5reyyGBOfwZz4HnJ2I6eZ7Ny@HgpWSEVBs4bz8SiFHbauuBnluMNM0R)

```
import re

regex = r"(?!(?<=\\x)|(?<=\\x[a-f\d]))([a-f\d]{2})"
test_str = r"30336237613131\x90\x01\x0A\x90\x02\x146F6D6D616E64\x90\x01\x06\x90\x02\x0F52656C6174\x90\x01\x02\x90\x02\x50656D31\x90\x00"
subst = r"\\x$1"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.IGNORECASE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

#### Explanation

- `(?!(?<=\\x)|(?<=\\x[a-f\d]))` Negative lookahead ensuring either of the following doesn't match.

  - `(?<=\\x)` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is `\x`.
  - `(?<=\\x[a-f\d])` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is `\x` followed by a hexidecimal digit.
- `([a-f\d]{2})` Capture any two hexidecimal digits into capture group 1.